# R: remove substring and change the remaining string by addition of a number

Tags: r, string

in R: I have some strings with the following pattern of letters and numbers

```
A11B3XyC4
A1B14C23XyC16
B14C23XyC16D3
B14C23C16D3
```

I want to remove the part "Xy" (always the same letters) and when I do this I want to increase the number behind the Letter B by one (everything else should stay the same).
When there is no "Xy" in the string there is no change to the string
The result should look like this:

```
A11B4C4
A1B15C23C16
B15C23C16D3
B14C23C16D3
```

Could you point me to a function capable of this? I struggle with doing a calculation (x+1) with a string.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `str_replace` to do the increment on the substring of numbers that follows the 'B' string after removing the 'Xy' only for cases where there is 'Xy' substring in `case_when`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
case_when(str_detect(str1, "Xy") ~ str_replace(str_remove(str1, 
   "Xy"), "(?<=B)(\\d+)", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 1), TRUE  ~str1)
[1] "A11B4C4"     "A1B15C23C16" "B15C23C16D3" "B14C23C16D3"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("A11B3XyC4", "A1B14C23XyC16", "B14C23XyC16D3", "B14C23C16D3")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfect. I did not know "case_when" - looks really handy!

Comment: @akrun: Genial. How it is this named when you call a function `function(x) as.numeric(x) +1 )` within this construct. So for the replacement argument in `str_replace` you take the first numeric after `B` change class to numeric and add 1. So you pass the value like we would do in my_func <- function(x) {as.numeric(x)+1  return(x)} ? So to summarise one can put a function in the replacement argument of str_replace? Many thanks!

Comment: @TarJae The `(?<=B)` is a regex lookaround, and the `(\\d+)` is captured as a group - i.e. one or more digits.  This captured group is converted to numeric by passing a function in replacemement and adding 1

Comment: @TarJae according to `?str_replace` - `replacement` - `Alternatively, pass a function to replacement: it will be called once for each match and its return value will be used to replace the match.`